# Superimpose on a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

`A` is my reference data-frame. It will **always** have **only one row**.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5], 'b': [3], 'c': ['C'], 'd' : ['D'], 'e' : ['E'], 'f' : [True], 'g' : [7]})
```

[image: A]

I want to use above data frame to replace `NA` and append missing columns in the below data frame. The index of `A` is ignored.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [0,1,np.nan, 1], 'e': ['Ex1', np.nan, 'Ex2', np.nan]})
```

[image: X]

The expected result is shown below.

[image]

Comment: @SamGinrich: Added. But I guess that is why we have `tags`.

Comment: When you spend 20 seconds to go through the list of currently open question you find it nice, when the title addresses topic and context, so you can on the fly decide, whether to enter a topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reindex` using the columns of `A` and then `.fillna` using the first (and only) row (as a Series) so that the filling aligns on the column labels.

Let pandas `'infer'` the downcasting so that the rows that can be cast to `int64` don't remain as `float64`, if that's important.

```
x = x.reindex(A.columns, axis=1).fillna(A.iloc[0], downcast='infer')

   a  b  c  d    e     f  g
0  1  0  C  D  Ex1  True  7
1  2  1  C  D    E  True  7
2  3  3  C  D  Ex2  True  7
3  4  1  C  D    E  True  7
```